# Hybris theme is not working in storefront

Tags: content-management-system, sap-commerce-cloud, storefront, mvc-storefront

HYBRIS 6.2.0.0 :

I have configured my complete storefront, it was working well in my pc. when i used same code [After copied] in different Hybris pc with same  version of HCS i was not able to view theme in storefront, it just showing me HTML data and contents. I can search product, view product add in to my cart also, but theme is not working.

For same storefront its working ok for apparel and electronics sites but not for my new storefront.
Any help please..............

Comment: Do you have set the theme in your website? This is something related to the DB not the source code. That's why it won't work if you just copy/paste hybris. You must run a init/update system on each env and make sure that everyone share the same DB datas.

Comment: Almost all done @milap-patel you had solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some mismatch in hybris 6.2.0.0

Please set your website theme to theme-alpha or theme-lambda, i am sure it will be working perfect after it....

Comment: Great solution thanks it works for me dont know why this mismatch is there but you are right......Thanks Again